# Schedule HTTP requests at point in time

Tags: http, schedule

I need to schedule actions (HTTP requests is enough) at a certain point in time. Every programmed request will only run once.

Sure I could implement this myself; saving the event to a database, then have an event-loop check if an action should be launched.

However this is such a generic need, there must be an existing service for this general type of need, feels like something I shouldn't implement myself. Any ideas where this can be found? I'm thinking one could just specify the http request to be saved (uri, body, headers)

AWS sure has a way of doing this using Cloudwatch events with a cron configured at the specific point in time. But this is way to clunky IMO. Is there an existing service/solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Agenda-Rest](https://github.com/agenda/agenda-rest) is a solution that does exactly what I asked for. It has to be self hosted though, as there seems to be no commercial hosting of it. It's also not actively developed, which could very well be that it's pretty much feature complete. After all it's a small wrapper on top of the library Agenda.

There's an alternative, suggested in a GitHub issue of Agenda-Rest, called AgenDash build on top of the same library. It's actively developed, as of autumn 2022. It's primarily a UI on top of Agenda, but it has rest routes that can be called.

There are also several libraries in various languages that exposes this functionality provided a persistence mechanism

- [agenda](https://github.com/agenda/agenda) (nodejs + mongodb)
- [redbeat](https://github.com/sibson/redbeat) (python + redis)
- [db-scheduler](https://github.com/kagkarlsson/db-scheduler) (java + any rdbms)

I'm quite surprised that I can't find this functionality as a first class citizen in the public cloud providers.

Edit:
AWS introduced the feature [EventBridge Scheduler](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/scheduler/latest/UserGuide/schedule-types.html) in nov 2022. It does not allow for a http request per see, but things like invoke a lambda or post a message to a queue is possible. They support one-time schedules so no need for cron and no need for removing it later as mentioned in my question above.